# Code duplication when overloading addition operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Let’s take a simple class representing an interval as an example. I want it to support the following operations:

```
int main()
{
    Interval<double> i1(1, 2);
    Interval<double> i2(3, 4);

    i1   + 1.0;
    1.0  + i1;
    i1   + 1.0f;
    1.0f + i1;
    i1   + 1;
    1    + i1;
    i1   + i2;
}
```

A possible implementation is

```
template<typename Real>
class Interval
{
public:
    Interval(Real value)
        : lower(value), upper(value)
    { }

    template<typename Real2>
    Interval(Real2 value)
        : lower(value), upper(value)
    { }

    template<typename Real2>
    Interval(Real2 l, Real2 u)
        : lower(l), upper(u)
    { }

    Interval<Real>& operator += (Interval<Real> rhs)
    {
        lower += rhs.lower;
        upper += rhs.upper;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    Real lower, upper;
};

template<typename Real>
const Interval<Real> operator + (Interval<Real> i1, const Interval<Real>& i2)
{
    i1 += i2;
    return i1;
}

template<typename Real1, typename Real2>
const Interval<Real1> operator + (Interval<Real1> i1, const Real2& r2)
{
    i1 += r2;
    return i1;
}

template<typename Real1, typename Real2>
const Interval<Real2> operator + (const Real1& r1, Interval<Real2> i2)
{
    i2 += r1;
    return i2;
}
```

This has some code duplication. Is there a more ’economical’ implementation? What is the best practice?

Comment: No, I shouldn’t. But I am modifying a temporary copy.

Comment: In this case you can probably rely on the implicit conversions you constructors defined...

Comment: What code duplication you mean, that you want to avoid?

Comment: Just so you're aware, [Boost Interval](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm).

Comment: chris, absolutely. I just want to learn the best practice.

Comment: Slava, the three different “operator +.”

Comment: Oh hey, there we go: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c2b2c872f6a0997  I made an absurdity!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can minimize the number of overload functions by providing a constructor in `Interval` that takes just one argument of type `Real`.</strike>

Then, all you need to implement is:

```
template <typename Real>
Interval<Real> operator+(Interval<Real> const& lhs, Interval<Real> const& rhs)
```

**Update**

If I have a member function:

```
Interval operator + (const Interval& i2)
{
   Interval<Real> i1 = *this; 
   i1 += i2;
   return i1;
}
```

then, I am able to compile:

```
Interval<double> i1(1, 2);
Interval<double> i2(3, 4);

std::cout << (i1 + i2) << std::endl;

std::cout << (i1 + 1.0) << std::endl;
std::cout << (i1 + 1.0f) << std::endl;
std::cout << (i1 + 1) << std::endl;
```

However if I have a free function:

```
template<typename Real>
Interval<Real> operator + (Interval<Real> i1, const Interval<Real>& i2)
{
    i1 += i2;
    return i1;
}
```

Then, I get compiler errors for:

```
std::cout << (i1 + 1.0) << std::endl;
std::cout << (i1 + 1.0f) << std::endl;
std::cout << (i1 + 1) << std::endl;
```

I don't know why that is the case.

**Update 2**

Thanks to @MooingDuck, it's clear why a free function does not work but a member function works for the above lines.

*As a member function, there's no template deduction, so conversions come into play. As a free function, there's template deduction, which disallows user conversions.*

Comment: Are you sure? I thought so too at first. I can not, however, get that to work in Visual Studio 2013. Does my example program compile?

Comment: Member function does not behave as described: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df1670ac0e5e9a5

Comment: @MooingDuck, I didn't think `(1.0 + i1)` would work at all with a member function. I am puzzled that `(i1 + 1.0)` works with the member function but not with the free function.

Comment: Aha, got it! as a member function, there's no template deduction, so conversions come into play.  As a free function, there's template deduction, which disallows user conversions.

Comment: Then perhaps all of my three functions are required?

Comment: @Petter: After much trial and error: yes.  My best so far is nearly identical to what you started with: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44c6889a5dd6cce6